# fastest way to connect to a specific wifi

Tags: wireless, 18.04, network-manager, notification

In Ubuntu 18.04 there is a unique block of notifications in the top bar in the right corner, that contains the wifi indicator, sound volume, battery, etc.

Now to choose a different wifi I need to click 5 times:
- click on the top bar
- click on the current wifi connected
- click on choose network
- click on the wifi desired
- click connect.

In the older Ubuntu versions, there was a single notification for the wifi so I needed only to click two times:
- click on the wifi icon in the top bar
- click on the wifi I want to connect
Done!

There is a faster way to change/choose the wifi to connect in Ubuntu 18.04?
If necessary, by installing another program/script.

Thanks

Comment: Just an option— you can switch to Unity DE completely from GNOME https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/

Comment: iwconfig wlan0 essid <name> key <password>